# Python UnboundLocalError "Need help"

Tags: python

```
def rotate_word(word,number)
    for i in word:
        word_num = ord(i)
        new_word += chr(word_num + number)
return new_word
```

Hi guys, the code above is not working. This is a python function. When i run the program i will return an error: "UnboundLocalError: 'new_word' referenced before assignment"

what this means? Can anyone help me?

the output of my function would be:

print rotate_word('abc',5)

output: fgh

Comment: I already solve the issue.. I just declare the new_word = '' before the for happens. whew!

Comment: Next problem is what happens for `rotate_word('xyz',5)`?

Comment: yes, that the next problem. I'm trying to solve it now. or do you have any algo for it?

Comment: rotate_word('xyz',5) output would be: cdf

Comment: @NitsujFelisco I've updated my answer with a solution to the `('xyz', 5)` argument.

Answer (score 2):

You should define `new_word` before using it. Place this before the `for`:

```
new_word = ''
```

You are also missing an indentation for the return and a colon after the def. Here is a fixed version:

```
def rotate_word(word, number):
    new_word = ''
    for i in word:
        word_num = ord(i)
        new_char = chr(word_num + number)
        if new_char > 'z':
            new_char = chr(ord(new_char) - 26)
        new_word += new_char
    return new_word

print rotate_word('abc', 5)
print rotate_word('xyz', 3)
```

EDIT: I've updated your code so it wraps after `'z'`